# prestodb: Failed to launch presto server and no nodes running

Tags: presto

Below is the snapshot of the error

```
presto> select * from system.runtime.nodes;
Error running command: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
```

I tried using local IP address and `10.0.2.2` yet the same error occurs.

Comment: is it possible your service hasn't been started? check the logs from prestro, and provide the relevant error here. see [prestodb docu](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html) for more infos

Comment: Check whether presto server is running or not. Open localhost:8080 in your web browser, are your nodes visible there?

Comment: See [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to format your post (code).

Comment: @Geetika There's nothing at 8080...no nodes are visible

Comment: @rsajjan2 Have you added discovery.uri=<coordinator_ip>:8080 property in your nodes config.property file

Comment: whats does "bin/launcher run" returns? check If this is successful.

Comment: @Geetika I configured presto for standalone mode, Here is the copy of config.property file                                                            
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080

Comment: @Paresh  bin/launcher run outputs as "already started" but there are no nodes running..

Comment: @Hansa **server log** contains                                                    ERROR Discovery-4 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector Cannot connect to discovery server for refresh (collector/general): Lookup of collector failed for http://172.16.18.65:8080/v1/service/collector/general